# Conditional Form Laravel/Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to create a conditional form that adds a text input when a particular option is selected. I am looping through "colors" and one of the options is "Other". If "Other" is selected, I need to add in an input field in order to type the desired color. This is my current select form

```
   <div class="my-3 px-3 w-full overflow-hidden sm:my-3 sm:px-3 sm:w-full md:my-3 md:px-3 md:w-1/2 lg:my-3 lg:px-3 lg:w-1/2 xl:my-3 xl:px-3 xl:w-1/2">
       <span class="text-gray-700 text-sm"><strong>Select A Glove Color</strong></span>
         <select type="text" class="mt-0 block w-full px-0.5 border-0 border-b-2 border-gray-300 focus:ring-0 focus:border-black" wire:model="state.color" name="color" required>
            <option value="">Select a Glove Color</option>
               @foreach ($color as $item)
                 <option value="{{ $item->name }}">{{ $item->name }}</option>
               @endforeach
         </select>
    @error('state.color') <div class="block w-full text-red-600">{{ $message }}</div> @enderror
   </div>
```

When the option "Other" is selected, I want to add this input:

```
 <input type="text" class="mt-0 block w-full px-0.5 border-0 border-b-2 border-gray-300 
 focus:ring-0 focus:border-black" wire:model="state.color" name="color" placeholder="Specify 
 Colors">
```

I have tried a few different things, such as adding a wire:model to the option its self adding listeners to the option. I can't seem to get any result -- not even errors. Any help explaining this concept would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please share your livewire component for better understanding.

Comment: @Digvijay I actually figured it out, I will post my solution shortly. Ended up being simpler than I thought and of course, the answer was already out there. Thanks for responding.